# Integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-8x+5}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been trying this one for days and I can't seem to get it.
I tried:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-8x+5}}{x}dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{\left(x-4\right)^2-11}}{x}dx$$

and set
$$x-4 = \sqrt{11}\sec\theta $$

so
$$dx=\sqrt{11}\sec\theta \tan\theta d\theta $$

and I had
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-8x+5}}{x}dx = \int \:\frac{11\sec\theta \tan^2\theta }{\sqrt{11}\sec\theta \:+\:4}d\theta $$

and I got stuck right there.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: I've tried Trigonometric Substitution, but it became more complicated.

Comment: What trigonometric substitution? It looks like a homework to me.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to learn how to write math in the comment. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do it in the OP

Comment: put $x-4=\sqrt(11)ch(\theta)$

Comment: Put $u = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$. This reduces the last integral to a rational function. You should be able to do partial fractions then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility is to do an Euler substitution.
Let $$y=\sqrt{x^2-8x+5}-x$$
Then $$(y+x)^2=x^2-8x+5$$ and one solves to get 
$$x=\frac{5-y^2}{2(y+4)}$$

That implies that 
$$\sqrt{x^2-8x+5}=y+x=y+\frac{5-y^2}{2(y+4)}$$

Thus the integral reduces to a rational function. The denominator is not that bad, I get $(y+4)^2(5-y^2)$. I dont feel like calculating the rest but the remainder should be straightforward partial fraction decomposition. Good Luck !

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I didn't know about the Euler substitution method. However, I think this problem may have another solution because I get this problem from a book, and that book doesn't have the Euler substitution method. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @glider There are multiple ways to solve many of these integrals. Here the expression under the root factors, so for example if you have an integral with $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ you could write it as $\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}(x-1)$ then your substitution is $y=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Trig substitution complicates it. A hyperbolic one works better. I tried $x-4=cosh(\theta)$ and then used the identity $cosh(\theta)^2-sinh(\theta)^2)=1$ to get it into a form which is straightforward. $11\int{sinh(\theta)^2.d\theta\over 4+\sqrt{11}cosh(\theta)}$

Comment: It should be $x-4=\sqrt{11}\cosh t$.

Comment: @susan Can you hint me how to solve the integral $11\int{sinh(\theta)^2.d\theta\over 4+\sqrt{11}cosh(\theta)}$ ? I cannot figure it out. I tried u-sub, but it didn't work.